# remove divs based on jquery then reapply based on windows size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new at jquery and need help. I would like to know a way to remove divs at the start and then reapply an individual div based on the size of a window. It's an audio player, one for desktop and one for mobile. Both players are set to autoplay when the page loads. If I use .hide, the player that is hidden is the one that autoplays.

Code on website:

```
<section id="post-player">
    <div class="player-desktop">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="display:none" id="ap2" class="audioplayer-tobe skin-wave" data-scrubbg="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/scrubbg.png" data-scrubprog="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/scrubprog.png" data-videoTitle="Audio Video" data-type="normal" data-source="http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/221003112-scott-johnson-27-tms-880.mp3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="player-mobile">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="display:none" id="ap3" class="audioplayer-tobe skin-silver" data-scrubbg="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/scrubbg.png" data-scrubprog="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/scrubprog.png" data-videoTitle="Audio Video" data-type="normal" data-source="http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/221003112-scott-johnson-27-tms-880.mp3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS code:

```
function myFunction() {
if($(window).width() > 800)
{   
    //Code to run when greater than...
        $( "div" ).remove( ".player-mobile" );
}
else
{
    //Code to run when less than...
        $( "div" ).remove( ".player-desktop" );
}
}
myFunction();


$(window).resize(function() {
myFunction();
});
```

JS code at bottom of page for player to load settings:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    dzsap_init("#ap2", {
        autoplay: "on"
        ,disable_volume: 'off'
        ,skinwave_mode: 'small'
    });
    dzsap_init("#ap3", {
        autoplay: "on"
        ,disable_volume: 'on'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem. Combined both the JS and the JS at the bottom of the page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
if($(window).width() > 800)
{   
//Code to run when greater than...
    $( "div" ).remove( ".player-mobile" );
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    dzsap_init("#ap2", {
        autoplay: "on"
        ,disable_volume: 'off'
        ,skinwave_mode: 'small'
    });
    dzsap_init("#ap3", {
        autoplay: "off"
        ,disable_volume: 'on'
    });
});
} else {
//Code to run when less than...
    $( "div" ).remove( ".player-desktop" );
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    dzsap_init("#ap2", {
        autoplay: "off"
        ,disable_volume: 'off'
        ,skinwave_mode: 'small'
    });
    dzsap_init("#ap3", {
        autoplay: "on"
        ,disable_volume: 'on'
    });
});
} } myFunction();


$(window).resize(function() {
myFunction();});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't use CSS media queries instead JS?

Here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/hyo0q6n6/) showing you how to do that with only CSS, try to resize the result section.

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .player-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .player-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem I have is that I want to have it autoplay. When I do the above using CSS media and display:none, it autoplays the hidden player.

Another problem I've notice is that both are shown and then the player that has display:none disappears after two seconds, anyway to remove the delay?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery show & hide methods if providing the functionality in JS is a must otherwise it would be better practise & more performant to use CSS of which @Michelem has provided

```
if($(window).width() > 800){   
    //Code to run when greater than...
    $( ".player-mobile" ).hide();
    $( ".player-desktop" ).show();
}else{
    //Code to run when less than...
    $( ".player-desktop" ).hide();
    $( ".player-mobile" ).show();    
}
```

if you were using the remove method the syntax would be: $(selector).remove(); i.e  $( ".player-mobile" ).remove(); but that completely removes the element from the DOM

Comment: Problem I have (sorry I left it out in the question) is that these players autoplay when the page loads. Don't want to do hide (display:none) because the hidden player is the one that autoplays first.